# img in <div> not floating right

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is width 100%: Inside that div I am trying to float the image to the right.

```
<div class="card-panel valign-wrapper " 
   style="height: 50px; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 290px; 
   background: white; z-index:3; ">  
 <h5 class="valign" class="right-align">Beer Menu</h5> 

 <img id = "moreInfo"  style="vertical-align: middle; float: right" src="img/more.png" 
   height="30" width="30"> 
</div>
```

I have been playing with chrome inspect element trying a bunch of different ways to float the image to the right end of the screen and leave the text to the left but not working.

Here is an image with surrounding code:

[image]

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle. Nobody can solve your problem by image.

Comment: Can you post the entire div's code and please don't split it up with here is the div, here is whats inside. It is better just to put your entire divs code.

Comment: It does work here: http://jsfiddle.net/whnqz1md/

Comment: Is your image those 3 dots next to "Beer Menu"?

Comment: Fiddle in my last comment didnt save the css. Here is the fiddle with the css. Looks like something in my css is pulling it back left:
https://jsfiddle.net/oLs3wd54/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple suggestions:

1. Use a separate CSS file. It will be easier to keep track of your CSS. Different rules might be taking precedence and it will be more clear if you use a separate file. It will also be easier to debug your CSS issue.
2. I am not sure why you have your  with Beer Menu as a part of the class "right-align". Arent you aligning this left and trying to align the image of the three dots right? This is a little confusing.
3. You can always try the "right:0px;" CSS rule. I cant help you code something that works perfectly without being able to try it myself but that could solve your problem. You could also give "position:absolute;" a shot

Just be sure to clean up your CSS and it will all become easier.

EDIT:

Its not the best but adding this to your image worked for me:

```
right: 0px;
top: 10px;
position: absolute;
```

Comment: right align was a test I forgot to take out before posting, just to see if I could move the text the other way. To make sure it was not just an img thing. It did not move right either.

Comment: can you provide me with the URL of your page?

Answer (score 1):

by just looking at that screenshot, you might try to give your img a position of relative. that generally fixes float problems. but don't forget to clearfix your parent element so the div doesn't collapse on itself.

I would also recommend not positioning everything as fixed, usually run into responsive issues with that unless initially positioned by JS, if so, my bad.

but with float issues, its usually positioning that screws it up.

good luck!

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did, and it worked in my browser:

```
<h5 class="valign right-align" style="float:left">Beer Menu</h5>
```

While rest of the code remains the same.

Comment: that didnt change anything.

Answer (score -3):

Try putting them in a table and align the column content to right. Something like

```
<table style="width">
<tr>
<td><h5>Beer Menu</h5></td>
<td align="right"><img /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: that came out of the div

Comment: can you paste the html code after using the table tag

Comment: I would rather not use a table for this.

Comment: ok... but just saying , below code works fine :<div class="card-panel valign-wrapper " style="height: 50px; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 290px; background: white; z-index:3; ">
<table width=100%>
    <tr>
        <td>    <h5 class="valign" class="right-align">Beer Menu</h5> </td>
        <td>    <img id="moreInfo" style="vertical-align: middle; float: right" src="img/more.png" height="30" width="30"> </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</div>